# simplify: $AB(C+BD')+(AB)'$ boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

> My solution 
> $S= AB(C+BD')+(AB)'$
> $S= ABC + ABD' + A' + B'$
> How do I proceed from this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat $AB$ as a variable. If it is $0$ the whole expression is true; if it is $1$ the whole expression reduces to $C+BD'$. Thus we may simplify to
$$(AB)'+C+BD'=A'+B'+C+BD'$$
By the same logic, $B'+BD'=B'+D'$, so we further reduce to
$$A'+B'+C+D'$$